# Removing url prefixes in django

Tags: python, html, django, attributes

Here is my localhost url
`localhost: 127.0.0.1:/8000/searches/?q=css` I want to get rid of these: '?q='

I tried removing the name attributes from my html.

`<input type="text">`

Comment: Are you looking for what the `HttpRequest` might tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume this is the code:

```
<input type="text" name="q" value="">
```

Now

```
Request.POST/GET['q']
```

takes '**q**' as a variable to your value thereby making it needless to remove 'q=' from your url.